# Stardew Valley Fortune Teller meaning

Tags: stardew-valley

If the fortune teller (at the fair) says "I see you and (blank) in a dimly lit room. You seem serious, but not unhappy" What does she mean by that? For me, the name was Sam and I already married him, so what would that mean?

Answer (score 4):

The [wiki](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Stardew_Valley_Fair) notes the clairvoyant's booth in the Festival will say things based on your social status.

> This information is based on the Social Status you have with the villagers. She will tell you something about whichever two villagers are at the top of your Social menu.

It does not seem to have a lot of meaning specifically, and is more for fun.

Comment: Thanks, but what does she mean by saying that? When she said "I see you and Sam working on a farm together. You seem happy about something." She meant marriage.

Comment: As i said , It does not usually have a meaning. It just picks one of the 2 people who have the most friendship with you and then does some message with them. Of course, one of your top 2 is probably going to be your marriage candidate, and if its a bachelor/ett, it will probably do a canned message about marriage, which you can then make fake if you tried.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I just did not understand before. :)